# How to override FAPI AHAH bindings?

Tags: 6, javascript, ajax

In Drupal 6, I am not happy with the default values for #ahah['event'].

What I want is the effect of having #ahah['keypress'] but when it is set, it also overrides any #ahah['event'].
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#ahah

Besides having the form submitted via AJAX when the 'ENTER' key is pressed, I also want the form submitted every 3 seconds after a change is made in the AHAH textfield, but I don't want both types of events to collide and to send the same request nearly at the same time.

Thus, I want to be able to override the AHAH bindings, and create my own events which will trigger my own action which will in turn call the AHAH backend, with the returned result being handled by Drupal in the normal way.

I am currently studying drupal.js, ahah.js and form.inc in hope of understanding how it all works and finding a solution. But I am afraid it's all above my pay grade. Hence this question. Thanks.

I am also wondering if I am not better off by not using FAPI '#ahah' at all and create everything on my own directly using jquery, bypassing FAPI '#ahah'...